# Minimum steps to sort array

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms

Consider you have a permutation of $1$ to $n$ in an array $array$. Now select three distinct indices $i$,$j$,$k$, there is no need  to be sorted. Let $array_i$, $array_j$ and $array_k$ be the values at those indices and now you make a right shift to it, that is $new$ $array_i$= $old$ $array_j$ and 
$new$ $array_j$= $ old$ $array_k$ and $new$ $array_k$=$old$ $array_i$. Find the minimum number of operations required to sort the array or if is impossible how to determine it.

Example :
Consider $array= [3,1,2]$; consider indices $(1,3,2)$ in the given order after applying one operation it is $s =[1,3,2]$.

Can anybody share your approach.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus can you suggest any algorithm?

Comment: By the way, applying the operation $(1,3,2)$ to the array $[3,1,2]$ gives the array $[2,3,1]$. If we instead applied $(1,2,3)$, we would get $[1,2,3]$.

Comment: The permutation $[3,1,2]$ is even. It's a 3-cycle.

Comment: Oh sorry ,and Thank you for the answer

Comment: This question appears to be about a problem from an [ongoing contest](https://www.codechef.com/MAY20B/problems/TRPLSRT). Please edit the question to clearly indicate the source of your problem. I will close this question for now while the source is unclear.  We require you to attribute the source of all copied material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operations correspond to applying a 3-cycle on the input permutation. You can reach the identity by applying 3-cycles iff the input permutation is even. Given the cycle decomposition of the input permutation, it shouldn't be hard to answer your question (though the answer is not immediate).

Comment: You will have to look these terms up. The Wikipedia page on the [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) should contain all the information you need (and a lot of it that you don't need).

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914338/the-alternating-group-is-generated-by-three-cycles); the alternating group consists of all even permutations.

Comment: No, you need to use permutations.

Comment: I already gave a hint. That's my answer. If you are not familiar with permutations and their cycle decomposition, I think you'll have a hard time solving this question.

Comment: Could  [4,3,2,1] sorted,as it can be represented as (1,4) and (2,3),it is even

Comment: Since it's even, it can be sorted. The question I linked to above describes how (or you can work it out yourself).

Comment: I think you just helped someone with an open coding contest problem.

Comment: Fortunately my answer is rather lacking in detail.